# Best seller sort order pagination query string not working correctly

Tags: magento-1.9, product-sorting

our website having two sort order. one is position and another is best seller.
but when i select the best seller sort order that time showing all the best seller products. but problem  when select category under best seller and going to 2 page or 3 page pagination that time 1st page is showing. not working pagination when select the best seller.

when select position sort order and category then url look like and pagination working correct

```
 www.website.com/kit/kit-faucet.html?p=1&cat=555
 www.website.com/kit/kit-faucet.html?p=2&cat=555
```

when select bestseller sort order and category then url look like and cat query string not display in url

```
www.website.com/kit/kit-faucet.html?p=1
 www.website.com/kit/kit-faucet.html?p=2
```

Comment: Have you check consol or magento log files?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i checked but not showing any error

Comment: Can you update your code for bestseller sorting you have used? Or any module you have used?

Comment: I have added only one product attribute name is 'best seller'

Comment: @ Sukemar I have not created any code or module that one priviously is working correctly

Comment: @SukumarGorai i have updated question please check

Comment: without sorting is it working correctly?

Comment: yes is working correctly but when i select any layered navigation menu then pagination not working correctly